# vmnet0 is missing in VMware Workstation Pro 16

Tags: windows-11, vmware-workstation

I’ve tried:

1. Reinstalling VMware workstation pro 16 several times.
2. Repairing the application through ‘Modify’.
3. Restoring defaults through the virtual network editor.
4. Running VMware on administrator mode.
5. Turning off my firewall and antivirus.

Nothing has seemed to work and I’ve decided I’d post here. Any help would be appreciated!

My host machine is windows 11 (not sure if that’s of any relevance)

Answer (score 0):

The default network connection for VMware Workstation is NAT.  Assuming you use NAT, then in ordinary VMware usage, VMNet0 (Bridged connection) does not show up.

I am using Windows 11 Pro, VMware V17 (same as V16 for this purpose).

See the first screen shot

[image: VM Network Editor non admin]

Open VMware Network Editor (All Programs).

Lower Right, Change Settings,  click on Change and OK the UAC Prompt

Now see VMNet0

[image: VM Network Editor with VMNet0]

Comment: I’ve done that and VMnet0 never shows up. I tried installing VMware on another pc and it worked just fine so I’m not really sure what’s wrong since I turned my firewall off before reinstalling. 

I’m gonna wipe my pc and try again and see if it’s any different.

Comment: tried installing VMware on another pc and it worked just fine  .... So my answer above is correct.   I am sure it will work on a fresh install of Windows.  Works fine for me here.

Comment: Update: wiped my pc and installed VMware and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I believe you should accept my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when VMNet0 is assigned to a *specific* network adapter attached to/in the PC, as opposed to the default setting of *"Automatic"* and then that adapter is removed/unplugged (eg ethernet port on a docking station, or USB-to-Ethernet dongle). Confirm if that is you specific scenario.